Mitigating Performance Bottlenecks and Freezing Issues on Jetson Xavier NX with YOLOv8 Models
Freezing problem with Jetson XavierNX
The lags and freezing issues I encounter when running my YOLOv8-trained model on Jetson Xavier NX are seriously hindering the progress of my project. These issues pose a major problem, especially for real-time image processing applications. Delays from starting the model can be up to 20 seconds, and frequent freezes occur during the process. Such performance problems both reduce the efficiency of the application and negatively affect the user experience.
How can I speed up Jetson Xavier NX?
